# Identify a value with special character for another field in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, argparse

I'm making a CLI based To-Do list app using python and there are the following fields: ['T.No', 'Date', 'Task', 'Project', 'Context', 'Message', 'Status']

So what I want is when I enter the task for example "meet @Sam and @Jack"
the code recognizes Sam and Jack with '@' and store them in 'Context' column
sample csv file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mosno15x3XaBMN4k93E8fFwi32pvmXdP

I wrote a code that identifies with @ but it doesn't include all the values if there are more than one words starting with '@' also it produces an error if there are no words starting with '@'.

```py
import csv
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', metavar='', help='-o <option> write either you want to add or view')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--task', metavar='', help='-t <task> Enter the task you want to add in the list')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--msg', metavar='', help='-d <description>Enter the description of the task you want to add')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--done', metavar='', help='-s Enter the status Complete if it is', default='Incomplete')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--project', metavar='', help='-d <project> Enter the project name')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--select', metavar='', help='-l <used to select the task for modification')
args = parser.parse_args()

    def addtask():
        r = args.task.split()
        for i in r:
            if i.startswith("@"):
                q = i
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        t = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        writer.writerow({'T.No': x, 'Date': t, 'Task': args.task, 'Project': args.project,
                         'Context': q, 'Message': args.msg, 'Status': args.done})
        print('TASK ADDED SUCCESSFULLY')
```

It doesn't recognize multiple words starting with '@' and produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "todoarg.py", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "todoarg.py", line 109, in main
    addtask()
  File "todoarg.py", line 44, in addtask
    'Context': q, 'Message': args.msg, 'Status': args.done})
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'q' referenced before assignment
```

when there are no words starting with '@'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember all your `q` in a list and then interate the list to write a new row for each q:

```
def addtask():
    r = args.task.split()
    qs = []
    for i in r:
        if i.startswith("@"):
            qs.append(i)
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    for q in qs: 
        writer.writerow({'T.No': x, 'Date': t, 'Task': args.task, 'Project': args.project,
                     'Context': q, 'Message': args.msg, 'Status': args.done})
    print('TASK ADDED SUCCESSFULLY')
```

You could also combine the two loops and write the row directly instead of appending to a list first.

---

Edit: after the clarification, that you don't want a row for each context:

```
def addtask():
    r = args.task.split()
    qs = []
    for i in r:
        if i.startswith("@"):
            qs.append(i)
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    q = ",".join( qs )
    writer.writerow({'T.No': x, 'Date': t, 'Task': args.task, 'Project': args.project,
                    'Context': q, 'Message': args.msg, 'Status': args.done})
    print('TASK ADDED SUCCESSFULLY')
```

Comment: I tried this but it creates two separate rows of same values in all fields except context, like it creates two separate rows. I want that if there are more than one words starting with '@' they combine in the same row also it doesn't solve the problem of throwing an error if there are no words starting with '@' present

Comment: see updated answer. this will create a comma separted string of your ``q``s. If you want a different separator just change the ``",".join( qs )`` part

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for the help sorry for the late response, this solved it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a variable before the for loop and this will all of the string starting with & to a list:

```
r = args.task.split()
q = []
for i in r:
    if i.startswith("@"):
        q.append(i)
```

Comment: I tried this but it creates two separate rows of same values in all fields except context, like it creates two separate rows. I want that if there are more than one words starting with '@' they combine in the same row also it doesn't solve the problem of throwing an error if there are no words starting with '@' present